# For what values of $b$ is $X_{t}=e^{bt+ \sigma w_t}$ a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

My attempt at a solution is:

For $s<t$

$E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=X_s \\ E[e^{bt}\cdot e^{\sigma}w_t]=e^{bs}e^{\sigma w_s}$

$e^{b(t-s)}E[e^{\sigma (w_t-w_s+w_s)}]=e^{\sigma w_s}$

$e^{b(t-s)}\cdot e^{\sigma w_s} E[e^{\sigma (w_t-w_s)}] = e^{\sigma w_s}$

The expected value is the Moment Generating Function for the variable $(w_t-w_s)$, and we simplify the term $e^{\sigma w_s}$ at each side

$e^{b(t-s)}\cdot e^{\frac{\sigma ^2}{2} (w_t-w_s)}=1$

Therefore

$b = -\frac{\sigma ^2 (w_t-w_s)}{2(t-s)}$

I'm pretty sure this is wrong, since according to my answer $b$ would depend from $(w_t-w_s)$. I was wondering if anyone has any pointers or other methods I can try.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(e^{\sigma(W_t-W_s)}) \neq e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}(W_t-W_s)}$... note that the left-hand side is a constant whereas the right-hand side is a (non-trivial) random variable... this shows that there is something off.

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As saz pointed out, the application of the MGF is not correct. I'm not sure if that made the solution clear staright away, but here's my go at a more rigorous answer. We have as given, adding implied initial value of $X_0=1$
$$X_t=X_0e^{bt+\sigma W_t}$$
Let some variable $Y$ be the exponent, that is $Y=bt+\sigma W_t$.
The moment generating function of a normal r.v. $Y\sim N(b,\sigma^2)$ is
$$M_Y(s)=E(e^{sY})=e^{bs+\frac{\sigma^2 s^2}{2}},\quad -\infty<s<\infty$$
So, for a BM with drift, as here, we have $Y(t)\sim N(bt,\sigma^2t)$, leading to
$$M_{Y(t)}(s)=E(e^{sY(t)})=e^{bts+\frac{\sigma^2ts^2}{2}},\quad -\infty<s<\infty$$
So, using the MGF, the first moment is given by
$$E(X(t))=E(X_0e^{Y(t)})=X_0M_{Y(t)}(1)=X_0e^{bt\cdot1+\frac{\sigma^2t\cdot1^2}{2}}<=>$$
$$E(X(t))=X_0e^{(b+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t}$$
Thus, to satisfy the martingale condition, we see that we must have
$$b=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$$